# Custom dialog does not show button

Tags: android, dialog

I'm creating a simple Dialog with two fields: an EditText and a Button. The EditText shows up, but the Button does now.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edittext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true" />
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/common_button_ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then simply:

```
    @Override protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
      final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.simple_edittext_and_button);
      EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
          dialog.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
            new SendReceipt(id, editText, mRefId.getValue().toString()));

        ....
```

There are no exceptions and no errors; simply the EditText shows up but not the button. Any ideas?

Comment: I would take a look at [AlertDialogSamples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html) It really helped me out when I was figuring this stuff out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong xml for vertical layout

```
orientation="vertical"
```

should be

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Your button is being layed out to the right of the edit text and doesn't show.